# Java Math.sin Math.cos Math.tan Giving answer in Radian

Tags: java, math

I was trying to use the Math library in Java where Math.sin(90) gives me result **0.8939966636005579** I search on StackOverflow about this and came to know that the value is) in radian so I used below code to convert it to a degree.

```
Double deg;
deg = Math.toDegrees(value);
```

The value of sin(90) in degree is 1 but the above code returns 51.222235723088794 what should I do to get an accurate result?

Result should be like for sin(90) :: 1

Comment: Since `Math.sin` works with radians you need to provide them. I am not sure what you are trying to do with `Math.toDegrees` since it converts radians to degrees. What you need `Math.toRadians` and convert degrees to radians which you will be able to pass to `sin` or `cos` methods.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP should be able to read and understand documentation.

Comment: You need to convert the radians to degrees; at the moment you are converting the sin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `double result = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90))`

Answer (score 1):

The trigonometric function take their **argument** in radian, their value is a ratio of lengths and thus dimensionless. You have to employ

```
value = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleInDegree))
```

etc. to get the trig. values for angles measured in degrees.